# CSS Bootstrap em combobox Ajax

Tags: css, ajax, bootstrap

Estou utilizando uma combobox ajax, para que possa ser digitado dentro dos dados da combobox, porém eu estou usando bootstrap e ele não fica configurado corretamente, eu utilizo class pra configurar, segue como está ficando:

```html
<div class="grid-16 search">
  <div class="grid-3">
    <asp:Label ID="labelPersonSituation" runat="server" Text="Situação da Pessoa:"></asp:Label>
    <select id="Situation" runat="server" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Todos">Todos</option>
                            <option value="Ativo">Ativo</option>
                            <option value="Bloqueado">Bloqueado</option>
                            <option value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
                            <option value="Livre">Livre</option>
                        </select>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-6">

    <asp:Label ID="labelModality" runat="server" Text="Modalidade:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ComboBox ID="DropModality" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoPostBack="False" CaseSensitive="False" ItemInsertLocation="Append" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" class="WindowsStyle"></asp:ComboBox>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-3">
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRelatorioAlunosSituacao" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" OnClick="btnRelatorioAlunosSituacao_Click" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
  </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ele fica dessa forma. Ele funciona a pesquisa, mas não funciona o css do bootstrap.

Descobri que ele está dando conflito com o ajax que estou utilizando, olha como está o css que ele utiliza do ajax:

```css
.ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: ButtonFace;
  height: 0px;
  width: 15px;
}

.ajax__combobox_itemlist {
  background-color: brown;
  border: solid 1px ButtonShadow;
  color: WindowText;
  cursor: default;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.ajax__combobox_itemlist li {
  padding: 0 3px 0 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.ajax__combobox_inputcontainer {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.ajax__combobox_inputcontainer td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: pode postar um pouco  mais do seu codigo?
e também  qual versão do bootstrap está utilizando

Comment: Estou utilizando a versão 3.3.7 @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons. 
O problema ocorre só no combobox nesta parte, ele é preenchido pelo banco de dados, sem o class="form-control" ele fica só o combobox corretamente, ai na imagem está somente o combobox, aparece estes dois itens.

Comment: Tenta postar o código html mais completo, com a `<head>` e o CSS que estiver usando se tiver.

Comment: Atualizei com html completo, eu não utilizo outro css a não ser o da classe bootstrap. que é o class="form-control"

Answer (score 0):

Bom seu css do bootstrap deve estar sendo interferido por algum  elemento externo

tente o seguinte

```
<div class="grid-6">
    <div style='float:left;marin-top:15px'>
       <asp:Label ID="labelModality" runat="server" Text="Modalidade:">
       </asp:Label>
       <asp:ComboBox ID="DropModality" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoPostBack="False" CaseSensitive="False" ItemInsertLocation="Append" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" class="WindowsStyle">
       </asp:ComboBox>
   </div>
</dib>
```

caso ainda esteja fora da borda aumnte o valor do margin
marin-top:15px até ajustar

Comment: Não funcionou, do mesmo jeito, mexendo e alterando o margin-top, sempre aparece como um textbox abaixo do combobox.

Comment: hmmm, de alguma forma seu  css pode estar alterado ou  sendo  contaminado por outro, se  tiver como  postar em  algum local para que possa inspecionar os elementos

Comment: Atualizei o código com o css que está dando o conflito.